# Qtiplot compiling ubuntu 18.04 copiling help

Tags: 18.04, compiling

I'd like to install Qtiplot, that is an opensource application for data analysis. Unfortunately I've not found free non-demo binaries, as the author ask to be payed for them. So, could someone explain me how to compile it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to compile it, unless you need to install its latest version, because QtiPlot (version 0.9.8.9-17) is available in the default Ubuntu repositories. You can install it by running:

```
sudo apt install qtiplot
```

Comment: Unfortunately this installs a version that has limits, like you can't open Origin files for example (if you try you have an error message saying you have to buy the feature). While the binaries on the QtiPlot websites can do that, but they does not allow to save any file and the widow close automatically after 20 minutes.

Comment: You can download the .tar.bz2 file form [here](https://www.qtiplot.com/download.html). Extract its contents and open the README.html to read the compiling instructions. Unfortunately, I don't have the time right now to test it and provide you with a proper answer. Perhaps I will do it tomorrow or the day after. You can try, however, by yourself and if you have a problem, ping me here and maybe I will be able to help.

Comment: @Stefano Sorry for the delay. I haven't been able to compile it correctly. Did you, by any chance, have better luck?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sorry for the late, I think I lost the notification. No, at the end I used it trying to deal with the limits imposed by the author for the non-payed version. I thought it was easier to compile it, unfortunately I had not time to made the necessary trials for the moment.